# Arcpy: List to point feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, list

I have a list of lists that contains:

```
[vala, valb, valc, vald, (pntx, pnty)]
[vala, valb, valc, vald, (pntx, pnty)]
[vala, valb, valc, vald, (pntx, pnty)]
```

I also have a list of the field names that correspond to vala, valb, etc.

I am trying to use arcpy to create a feature class with all the information from the list, with the proper field names from the list of field names.

As I want the FC to be a point layer, I thought about using add XY event layer, however there seems to be no option for adding a field list and my x,y coordinates are in a tuple instead of individual list positions for indexing. I could probably create an empty feature class and use an insert cursor, but then how do I deal with the geometry?

I am using ArcMap 10.0.

Comment: Have you looked at the ESRI help section on writing geometries? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001v000000

Comment: This Q/A works best if you post your attempted code in your question so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks. The code is pretty long and irrelevant to this problem that's why I don't want to post it. I read through the writing geometries stuff and I am now creating a feature class and will attempt to write the tuples to geometry objects. I was really looking for help on the basic algorithm..

I am creating a new feature class using a template with similar field names, then I will use an insert cursor and a for loop to populate the fields from my lists of lists. I think, this is quite new to me.

Comment: It should always be possible, and preferred, to load a code snippet that works up to the point where you are stuck.

Comment: yes but that would not work in this situation as it was the algorithm that I was struggling with. I posted what my variables were and what I was trying to do with them. @radouxju was able to figure out exactly what I was asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with 10.1, you'll need to use arcpy.da.insertcursor with the SHAPE@XY token

```
c = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(emptyshapefil, 
                          ("NAMEa", "NAMEb", "NAMEc", "NAMEd", "SHAPE@XY"))

for row in yourlist:
    c.insertRow(row)
```

with 10.0 it is more complicated. you'll need arcpy.insertCursor and point geometry

```
c = arcpy.InsertCursor(emptyshapefile)

for row in yourlist:
    feat = c.newRow()   
#attributes
    feat.NAMEa = row[0]
    feat.NAMEb = row[1]
    feat.NAMEc = row[2]
    feat.NAMEd = row[3]
#geometry 
    pnt = arcpy.Point()
    pnt.X = row[4][0]
    pnt.Y = row[4][1]
    feat.shape = pnt
    c.insertRow(feat)
del feat, c
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am using 10.0 so do not have access to the the arcpy.da module.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly! My field list is much longer than stated so I will try and write a for loop to assign the field names to the list positions but the basic idea is there, I really appreciate your help. Just one question though; what is the i=0 for?

Comment: I have removed i=0. initially I wanted to use it for the FID, but in fact it is auto-incremented and I forgot to remove it.